# Django flatpages middleware

Tags: django

I am unable to get the flatpages app to work correctly when using FlatpageFallbackMiddleware - it produces a 404 error when I go to /about/.  Although it does display the page correctly when I remove the middleware and just hard-code the URL in to my root urls.py.

Below are some of the sections of code that seem to be relevant based on what I've read so far:

Site settings:

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

Middleware settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware',
    'codex.core.middleware.AuditTrailMiddleware',
]
```

The flatpage I've created:

[image]

The result I get:

[image]

I've tried reordering the middleware, I've tried commenting out some of the non-standard middleware to see if that was interfering with the flatpages middleware, but I still get a 404.

I am happy to provide any relevant screenshots or code if anybody can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

EDITED TO ADD:

[image]

Root urlconf:

[image]

Comment: how about `INSTALLED_APPS`, and the root urlconf ?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Django
    'flat_responsive',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',

# Rest is too long to fit in comment
]

Comment: Edit the question please

Comment: Done - thanks that's a better way of doing it.

Comment: Great. Screenshots are usually frowned upon. Please copy-paste text.. Anyway, check the answer. There would be your issue

Comment: Sorry, I've relatively new to the site but I'll remember that for the future.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not look like there is an entry to include the flatpage urls.

It would look something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
]
```

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/flatpages/)

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.  I had thought that when using the middleware, that it no longer needed to be included in the urls.  I'll go and have a closer read of the documentation.  Thanks again for your help!